# Why "df -h " does not show the root mount, but multiple repetitive entries?

Tags: mount, filesystem, openvz

The system is Ubuntu 10.04 running on a OpenVZ VPS

Here is the output:

```
root@s01:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
varrun                256M   20K  256M   1% /var/run
varlock               256M     0  256M   0% /var/lock
varrun                256M   20K  256M   1% /var/run
varlock               256M     0  256M   0% /var/lock
varrun                256M   20K  256M   1% /var/run
varlock               256M     0  256M   0% /var/lock
varrun                256M   20K  256M   1% /var/run
varlock               256M     0  256M   0% /var/lock
varrun                256M   20K  256M   1% /var/run
varlock               256M     0  256M   0% /var/loc
root@s01:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the ultimate source of the problem, something in the upstart scripts and running in openvz.

I do not think it is causing any problem and is safe to ignore.

If you wish, pastebin your `/ect/init/openvz.conf` and I will review it.

You can try commenting out these lines:

```
mount -t tmpfs varrun /var/run
mount -t tmpfs varlock /var/lock
```

BUT I would not do that if you do not have access to the VPS from the host as if your change prevents it from booting, you will have a useless VPS.

There is a discussion of this exact behavior on the [OpenVZ Forums](http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=41340&) , but without any conclusion.

Comment: This is the /ect/init/openvz.conf : http://pastebin.com/rKVzF3br
Also, on every restart df -h shows two more entries, so they keep incrementing...

Comment: Shut down the guest (from the host), comment out those two lines, and restart the guest.

Comment: Do you know why / is missing, how can I know the disk space used? Thanks!

Comment: This configuration is on the guest, not the host. The host is some VPS provider.

Comment: Yes, you edit `/etc/init/openvz.conf` in the guest, not the host. Again, if you do not have access to the host node, I would leave it as is ;)

Comment: I have commented these two lines, removed the repetitive entries from /etc/mtab , restarted and now it is ok, there are only two and  they do not increment afer restart. Still, there is no root mount, but the disk space is displayed in the existing entries. Don't know if this is correct, but seems to work.